# Nearest nodes to a give node, assigning dynamically weight to relationship types

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to find the N nodes "nearest" to a given node in a graph, meaning the ones with least combined weight of relationships along the path from given node.
Is is possible to do so with a pure Cypher only solution? I was looking about path functions but couldn't find a viable way to express my query.

Moreover, is it possible to assign a default weight to a relationship at query time, according to its type/label (or somehow else map the relationship type to the weight)? The idea is to experiment with different weights without having to change a property for every relationship.
Otherwise I would have to change the weight property's value to each relationship and re-do it to before each query, which is very time-consuming (my graph has around 10M relationships).
Again, a pure Cypher solution would be the best, or please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you looked at REDUCE? You can easily sum relationship weights over a path and return k nodes with the lowest sum using LIMIT k. http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-functions-collection.html#functions-reduce

Answer (score 2):

Please use variable length Cypher queries to find the nearest nodes from a single node.

```
MATCH (n:Start { id: 0 }),
  (n)-[:CONNECTED*0..2]-(x)
RETURN x
```

Note that the syntax `[CONNECTED*0..2]` is a range parameter specifying the min and max relationship distance from a given node, with relationship type `CONNECTED`.

You can swap this relationship type for other types.

In the case you wanted to traverse variably from the start node to surrounding nodes but constrain via a stop criteria to a threshold, that is a bit more difficult. For these kinds of things it is useful to get acquainted with Neo4j's spatial plugin. A good starting point to learn more about Neo4j spatial can be found in this blog post: http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-spatial-part1-finding-things-close-to-other-things

The post is a little outdated but if you do some Google searching you can find more updated materials.

GitHub repository: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial