# Neo4j first node to meet relationship in a movie model

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have read the Neo4j manual and saw the numerous short examples regarding movie graph. I have also installed it locally and played with the cypher.

Here is the setup:
I have the following nodes: Movies (with name and id, owned by friend), Actors(with name and ids) Directors (with names and id), Genre (with id and name)

Relations are: Actors acted in Movies (1 movie - many actors), Directors directed a movie (1 director per movie but a director can direct many movies), and Movies has several genre "(many to many)

1) Owned by friend I dont know why but following the LOAD CSV example they put USA as a node rather than a property but is there a logical reason why its better to put it as a node rather than a property like i did?

2)
What I want to search is similar to the answer given to this question:
[Nearest nodes to a give node, assigning dynamically weight to relationship types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074477/nearest-nodes-to-a-give-node-assigning-dynamically-weight-to-relationship-types)

However - I do not have a weight on the relationship and its more of a "go find the first give nodes connected to it"

Given that the "owned by friend" can only be owned by 1 person.

If given movie title "Spider-Man" (which for example purpose is owned by frank) go find the next occurrence of a movie that is owned by John.

So after reading Neo4j I believe that I dont need to specify which relationship is needed to traverse but just go find the next movie that meets my criteria, right?

So Following the above link

```
MATCH (n:Start { title: 'Spider-Man' }),
  (n)-[:CONNECTED*0..2]-(x)
RETURN x
```

So go to node Spider-Man and go find me X as long as it is connected but I got stump by *0..2 because its the range...what if I just say "go find me the first you that means the own by John"

3) following up to #2 - how do i insert the fitler "own by john" ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things in your question that don't quite make sense. Here's a stab at an answer.

1) Making 'USA' a node rather than a property is useful if you want to search based on country. If 'USA' is a node, you are able to limit your search by starting at the 'USA' node. If you don't care to do this, then it doesn't really matter. It may also save a small amount of space for longer country names to store the name once and link to it via relationships.

2) Your example doesn't match your described graph. I can't really speak to it without a better example.

3) This is probably easy to answer once you improve your example.

---

OK. Based on the comments to the answer, here's what you need. To find one movie owned by John that is connected via common actors, directors, etc to the movie Spider-man owned by Frank (that is, sub-graphs like (movie)<--(actor)-->(movie) ) you can write:

```
MATCH (n:Movie {title : 'Spider-Man', owned_by : 'Frank'})<-[*2]->(m:Movie {owned_by : 'John'})
RETURN m LIMIT 1
```

If you want more responses, alter or remove the LIMIT on the RETURN clause. If you want to allow chains that pass through chains like (movie)<--(actor)-->(movie)<--(director)-->(movie), you can increase the number of relationships matched (the *2) to 4, 6, 8, etc. You probably shouldn't just write the relationship part of the MATCH clause as -[*]-, because this could get into infinite loops.

Comment: what do you understand from the example specifically?

Let me try to phrase it this way: "if i have a property called tag that is part of the movie nodes, and i have 3 relationships that ties the movie nodes together, if given a starting point for a movie (ie a movie name) what is the proper cypher to go and find the first pair of nodes that has the given tag. The issue is that if I have 300K movie node entry and i have 50K node with the tag = 1 only what s the most effective way to find the first node that has tag =1 give name = "given search title". Is this more comprehensible?

Comment: Let me try to state the question. Starting with a given movie, how do you find a movie that has a specific property value and is related to the given movie through actors or directors? Is that right?

Comment: through a given X relationship. the relationships are from actors and directors but it can expand to writers, producters.... in the long run. But you got it more or less right.